# The maximum row size for the used table type, not counting BLOBs, is 65535. You have to change some columns to TEXT or BLOBs

Tags: mysql, max, multiple-columns, create-table

I am getting the below message on a table I am trying to create.

> The maximum row size for the used table type, not counting BLOBs, is 65535. You have to change some columns to TEXT or BLOBs

Anyone know the answer to this please?

```
-- Table `warrington_central`.`job`  
-- -----------------------------------------------------  

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `warrington_central`.`job` (  
  `id` MEDIUMINT(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,  
  `alias_title` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,  
  `reference_number` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL ,  
  `title` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,  
  `primary_category` SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,  
  `secondary_category` SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,  
  `tertiary_category` SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED NULL ,  
  `address_id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,  
  `geolocation_id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NULL ,  
  `company` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,  
  `description` VARCHAR(10000) NOT NULL ,  
  `skills_required` VARCHAR(10000) NOT NULL ,  
  `job_type` TINYINT(2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,  
  `experience_months_required` TINYINT(2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,  
  `experience_years_required` TINYINT(2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,  
  `salary_range` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL ,  
  `extra_benefits_above_salary` VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL ,  
  `available_from` DATE NULL ,  
  `available_to` DATE NULL ,  
  `extra_location_details` VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL ,  
  `contact_email` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL ,  
  `contact_phone_number` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL ,  
  `contact_mobile_number` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL ,  
  `terms_conditions_application` VARCHAR(5000) NOT NULL ,  
  `link_to_profile` ENUM('0','1') NOT NULL ,  
  `created_on` DATETIME NOT NULL ,  
  `updated_on` DATETIME NOT NULL ,  
  `updated_by` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,  
  `add_contact_form` ENUM('0','1') NOT NULL ,  
  `admin_package_id` TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,  
  `package_start_date` DATETIME NOT NULL ,  
  `package_end_date` DATETIME NULL ,  
  `package_comment` VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL ,  
  `viewable_to_members_only` ENUM('0','1') NOT NULL ,  
  `advertise_to` DATETIME NULL ,  
  `show_comment` ENUM('0','1') NOT NULL ,  
  `hits` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,  
  `visible` ENUM('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' ,  
  `approved` ENUM('I/* large SQL query (3.9 KB), snipped at 2,000 characters */
/* SQL Error (1118): Row size too large. The maximum row size for the used table type, not counting BLOBs, is 65535. You have to change some columns to TEXT or BLOBs */
SHOW WARNINGS;
```

Comment: which column do i need to change in this instance

Comment: is this not allowed description VARCHAR(10000) NOT NULL ,
skills_required VARCHAR(10000) NOT NULL ,

Comment: You need to do like the error message says - change some to `text` datatype. Enough so the row size, not including `blob` and `text` types, does not exceed 65535. Do you not understand the error message?

Comment: no sorry- which columns have incorrect data type

Comment: None of them have incorrect data type. It's the ROW that's the problem, not any single column. The row size is the sum of all columns. The docs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/column-count-limit.html

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Change `description` and `skills_required` to be type `text`

You are getting that message because the *sum* of all the fields is > 65k

Comment: so there is a limit across all columns on a row as well as for individual columns